# Why I cannot find Element.after() method in w3c Standard?

Tags: javascript, w3c

I cannot find the `after()` method defined in `Element` interface in Dom Standard.But the Chrome devtools shows an `after()` method in Element Node.

Element Interface Link: https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#element

So does `animate()` or `append()` method in Chrome devtools.Even if I search them on Node or `EventTarget` interface which the `Element` interface inherit from

The devtools shows Element Node like below:

```
HTMLBodyElement
HTMLElement
Element
after: ƒ after()
animate: ƒ animate()
append: ƒ append()
assignedSlot: (...)
attachShadow: ƒ attachShadow()
attributeStyleMap: (...)
attributes: (...)
baseURI: (...)
before: ƒ before()
```

The Chrome devtools shows inherit tree like this:body---> HTMLBodyElement---> HTMLElement---> Element---> Node---> EventTarget---> Object

Answer (score 0):

Because only elements that are child nodes have it.

> ```
> interface mixin ChildNode {
>   [CEReactions, Unscopable] void before((Node or DOMString)... nodes);
>   [CEReactions, Unscopable] void after((Node or DOMString)... nodes);
>   [CEReactions, Unscopable] void replaceWith((Node or DOMString)... nodes);
>   [CEReactions, Unscopable] void remove();
> };
> ```

[source](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#ref-for-nondocumenttypechildnode%E2%91%A1%E2%91%A0)

Comment: But, the devtools shows the inherit tree like this,no childNodes the Element inherit from? So why the Element node have the chideNodes method?                                           ```body--->
HTMLBodyElement--->
HTMLElement--->
Element--->
Node--->
EventTarget--->
Object```

Comment: Don't confuse a browser's implementation of the spec with how the spec is expressed. Don't confuse the ability of an element to *have* child nodes with an element **being** a child node itself.

Answer (score 0):

Why Element has ChildNode method?Because ,the ChildNode is a mixin node and it has been included to Element.The Standard Said like this:
https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#childnode

If you want to find how the browser do this.You can find a js version here:
https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom/blob/1c8e96319aed2c8eee144f235893f18155ffa596/lib/jsdom/living/nodes/Element-impl.js#L519